# allocating enough memory using typedef struct object whose size varies in another typedef struct 

Tags: struct, malloc, typedef

I have defined two `typedef struct`s, and the second has the first as an object:

```
typedef struct  
{
    int numFeatures;
    float* levelNums;

} Symbol;
typedef struct  
{
    int numSymbols;
    Symbol* symbols;    
} Data_Set;
```

I then defined `numFeatures` and `numSymbols` and allocate memory for both `symbols` and `levelNums`, then fill `levelNums` inside a for loop with value of the inner loop index just to verify it is working as expected.

```
Data_Set lung_cancer;
lung_cancer.numSymbols = 5;
lung_cancer.symbols = (Symbol*)malloc( lung_cancer.numSymbols * sizeof( Symbol ) );
lung_cancer.symbols->numFeatures = 3;
lung_cancer.symbols->levelNums = (float*)malloc( lung_cancer.symbols->numFeatures * sizeof( float ) );
for(int symbol = 0; symbol < lung_cancer.numSymbols; symbol++ )
    for( int feature = 0; feature < lung_cancer.symbols->numFeatures; feature++ )
        *(lung_cancer.symbols->levelNums + symbol * lung_cancer.symbols->numFeatures + feature ) = feature;
for(int symbol = 0; symbol < lung_cancer.numSymbols; symbol++ )
    for( int feature = 0; feature < lung_cancer.symbols->numFeatures; feature++ )
        cout << *(lung_cancer.symbols->levelNums + symbol * lung_cancer.symbols->numFeatures + feature ) << endl;
return 0;
```

When `levelNums` are `int` I get what I expect( i.e. 0,1,2,0,1,2,...) but when they are `float`, only the first 3 are correct and the remaining are very small or very large values, not 0,1,2 like expected. I then have two questions:

1. When allocating memory for `symbols`, how does it know how big a `Symbol` is since I have not yet defined how large `levelNums` will be yet.
2. How do I get `float` values into `levelNums` correctly.

The reason I am doing it like this is this is a data structure that will be sent to a GPU for GPGPU programming in CUDA and arrays are not recognized.  I can only send in a continuous block of memory explicitly and the `typedef struct`s are only there for conveying/defining the memory struture of the data.

Comment: I don't understand the CUDA part. If you have `int *ptr`, then `ptr[i]` is exactly the same as `*(ptr + i)`. Why are you doing these strange things?

Comment: What compiler are you using? I've tried your code on Ubuntu using gcc 4.4.3 and work as expected. In both, int and float, the results is 0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2...

Comment: @pQB g++.  I didn't expect any problems which is why I'm confused.

Comment: @kan CUDA is standard C only but will not still recognize things like ptr[i][j].  It will recognize ptr[i] I just didn't choose to do it that way.

Comment: Me too. This is not related with CUDA or GPGPU but with compiler/platform. Could you add g++ / operating system version ?

Comment: @pQB yeah, why does it say CUDA in front of my post now?  This is just running on the CPU for now, the object will eventually be sent to the GPU but not until our research project team is ready for that.  I am just constructing the data structure so it's ready for later.  I dont know what version of g++ or how to check that.  I am on MacOSX though.

Comment: @pQB I just typed in g++ and gcc by itself and it says 4.0.1, with i686-apple-darwin9 before it.  I also tried to use gcc to compile but it threw all kinds of undefined symbol errors, something about lazy_ptr and cctU6XEI.o.

Comment: @pQB I got it to work, I knew it had to do something with the allocation of memory!!  If I give it more memory then everything comes out fine.  Which leads me back to my first question, how do I set aside in advance enough memory for Symbol not knowing how big each Symbol will be, without doing what I did and setting aside a crap load lol!!

Comment: Just to know, is the sizeof(int) =sizeof(float) in your framework?

Comment: @pQB I don't understand the question

Comment: @pQB 2 things: (1) Since `sizeof(Symbol)` returns 8, without knowing how many `levelNums` there will be ahead of time, it will not allocate enough memory, and I can't set `levelNums` until the `Data_Set` object is declared, so I will have to set a variable ` num_of_levels *` before hand and multiply this by `sizeof(Symbol)` in the `malloc` to make sure there is enough memory allocated.  I am not sure how your's is working unless it dynamically allocates more. (2) I just found out I'm full of it, CUDA will accept `array[][]` like definitions so I won't have to deal with this anyways!!

Answer (score 0):

A couple thing jump out at meet. For one thing, you only allocated a buffer for levelNums of the first symbol. Similarly, your inner loops always loop over the numFeatures of the first symbol.

You're doing a whole lot of dereferencing of arrays, which is fine in general, but the assignment in particular (inside the first set of loops) looks very strange. It's entirely possible I just don't understand what you're trying to do there, but I think it'd be a lot less confusing if you used some square bracket array accessors.